# Unable to run Grails web app war in Tomacat 7 when try to access from Apache's common lib folder

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, grails, war

Created a web application in Grails. War file size is 47 MB. As the part of reducing war size, i moved all jar files from application's WEB-INF/lib folder to Apache's lib folder. But unable to start the Apache server.

Comment: That's bad, but what should we do now, without any information? See [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

Comment: Is there any possibility to access all jar files from Apache's lib folder instead of application's WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: If you mean Tomcats lib folder, yes they are added to the classpath, as well as the ones from your webapps lib folder. You need to post the error trace you get when starting the server.

Comment: The error is,  
15-Apr-2016 12:28:40.446 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core
.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component